# Write key to registry if Task has NOT been selected by user

Tags: inno-setup

With a Task defined as:

```
Name: "TaskAutoLogon"; Description: "{cm:TaskAutoLogon}"; Flags: unchecked
```

the user can choose whether to write a key to Registry like this:

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon; ValueType: dword; ValueName: AutoAdminLogon; ValueData: 1; Tasks: TaskAutoLogon
```

**My question is:**
How can I tell Inno Setup to write that key to Registry only if the Task has NOT been selected/checked?
I practically want to invert the meaning of the Task.

I know it can be done with some code in the [code] section, but I hope there is a more native way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for script code here. The [`Tasks`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) parameter supports `not` operator, so you can write `Tasks: not TaskAutoLogon` to process your entry when the task is not selected:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon; ValueType: dword; ValueName: AutoAdminLogon; ValueData: 1; Tasks: not TaskAutoLogon
```